# COM, return a DATE information

Tags: com

I need to return from a COM server a date information. I saw the DATE type in IDL which in C/C++ was mapped to a double type. When I return the date I would convert internally from SYSTEMTIME to double in order to match the required output type like this:

```
... comIFaceMethod(DATE* result)

{
SYSTEMTIME computed;
::SystemTimeToVariantTime(&computed, result);
}
```

Is this the correct way of transfering a date information through COM ? I ask this because this kind of works but I also see some strange results sometimes and don't know the reason. My last alternative would be to define my own SYSTEMTIME struct in COM to transfer results but I would prefer a better solution...

In the example above I compute "computed" some place else and I also validate result from SystemTimeToVariantTime conversion

Comment: Assuming you actually give the *computed* variable a proper value, yes, this is correct.  Not checking the return value is of course not correct.

Comment: @Hans, you mean not checking SystemTimeToVariantTime conversion as being OK, yes, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code sample showed a correct way of transferring date information through COM.
"I ask this because this kind of works but I also see some strange results sometimes" - it works now.